# Validate img url with Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I have been trying to validate a image url using regular expression like so:

```
#\[img\](((http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?(www.)?(([a-zA-Z0-9-]){2,}\.){1,4}([a-zA-Z]){2,6}(\/([a-zA-Z-_\/\.0-9#:?=&;,]*)?)?))\[\/img\]#iUs
```

i want be to able to replace:

`[img]http://www.website/folders/url_here.png[/img]`
`[img]https://www.website/folders/url_here.jpg[/img]`
`[img]https://www.website/folders/url_here.gif[/img]`

with:

`<img src="http(s):www.website/folders/url_here.png(jpg, gif)" />`

Using:

```
$new_string = preg_replace($search, $replace, $string);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<?php

$rgx = '/\[img\](https?:\/\/.+?\.(?:png|gif|jpg))\[\/img\]/';
$arr = array(
'sdvsvsdvsdv[img]http://www.website/folders/url_here.png[/img]sdvsdvsvdsvdsdv',
'sdvsvdsvd[img]https://www.website/folders/url_here.jpg[/img]svsnvlkn',
'sdvsdvsdv[img]https://www.website/folders/url_here.gif[/img]svdsvd'
);

$all = 'sdvsvsdvsdv[img]http://www.website/folders/url_here.png[/img]sdvsdvsvdsvdsdv
sdvsvdsvd[img]https://www.website/folders/url_here.jpg[/img]svsnvlknsdvsdvsdv[img]https://www.website/folders/url_here.gif[/img]svdsvd';

echo "Individual strings:\n";
foreach ($arr as $str) {
    echo preg_replace($rgx, '<img src="$1" alt="">', $str) . "\n";
}

echo "\nAll together: \n";
echo preg_replace($rgx, '<img src="$1" alt="">', $all) . "\n";
```

Codepad:
http://codepad.org/n00B6akn

**Some little tweaks:**

Alternatively this tweak speeds up the regex I made by keeping it greedy instead of making the middle non-greedy:

```
$rgx = '/\[img\](https?:\/\/[^\[]*\.(?:png|gif|jpg))\[\/img\]/'
```

And here without as many slashes:

```
$rgx = '~\[img\](https?://[^\[]*\.(?:png|gif|jpg))\[/img\]~'
```

It makes sure the img tags are matched, and that whatever is inbetween them starts with http(s):// and ends with .png / .gif / .jpg. If you need better validation then something like what hwnd made initially (v1 of his answer) is more fitting (given you tweak his solution to your needs).

Comment: You could eliminate some slashes there by using a different delimitor like Livewire did, I used an editor/tester where slashes are mandatory so I did not have that luxury.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following for this.

```
$text = <<<DATA
[img]http://www.website/folders/url_here.png[/img]
[img]https://www.website/folders/url_here.jpg[/img]
[img]https://www.website/folders/url_here.gif[/img]
DATA;

$text = preg_replace('~\[(img)\](https?://\S+\.(?:png|gif|jpg))\[/\1\]~', 
                     '<img src="$2" />', $text);
```

Output

```
<img src="http://www.website/folders/url_here.png" />
<img src="https://www.website/folders/url_here.jpg" />
<img src="https://www.website/folders/url_here.gif" />
```

See [Live demo](https://eval.in/153187)

Comment: This looks awesome as well, thank you, I will check both answers.

Comment: I admire you for going out of your way to validate the url but `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` only matches ascii urls correctly and also allows protocols other than just http and https, just had to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use something like:

```
$output = preg_replace('/\[img\]((?:https|http|ftp):\/\/.+?\.(?:png|gif|jpg))\[\/img\]/igm', '<img src="$1" alt="Image">', $input);
```

Where `$input` is your page of text and `$output` is your result. The regular expression evaluates the url and bbcode then adds it to a  tag. I have added the alt="" attribute just to make it more html valid. I have also allowed the ftp protocol as some ftp servers allow public access to image files.

The `/igm` makes it case insensitive, allows subsequent searches to start from the end of the previous match and will match the start and end of a line, instead of the start and end of the whole string.

Comment: This doesn't validate if the URL is valid

Comment: @hwnd I was hoping it could be optional, as to some websites use https

Comment: As far as validation goes, the url in your question is not valid.

Comment: @user2444411 Firstly your URL of `http(s):www.website/folders/url_here.png(jpg, gif)` isn't valid. But what I have here should finally work.

Comment: @limewire well i put the parentheses as an option to indicate it could be https or http and so for the image type.

Comment: Oh I see, anyway try what I have given you, It's a solution of some sort.

Comment: I try this, but i got a really wrong html tag, with parameters that don't exist

Comment: You literally just changed your answer into w/e I had half an hour after I posted mine... Points for originality: 0...